# how can I integrate ticketmaster api / sdk with yii2?

Tags: jquery, api, sdk, yii2

I m working on yii2 website and I want to integrate [ticketmaster](http://developer.ticketmaster.com) in my project to sell the event tickets, please give me some guidelines how to do it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad to answer. Have a read of the API documentation examples at http://developer.ticketmaster.com/products-and-docs/apis/getting-started/, and try out the API in your browser at http://developer.ticketmaster.com/api-explorer/.

A high level approach is to authenticate, find an attraction or event, add products, delivery method and payment to a cart, and checkout. To reserve and buy tickets use the Partner API.

API use cases

- Discovery API

  - Searching events by keyword in a certain location (lat/long).
  - Getting events for a particular artist OR venue in a specific country/city/zip code/DMA/etc.
  - Getting hi-res images for a particular event or artist.
  - Search events of a certain genre in a particular location for a certain promoter.
- Commerce API

  - Get available offers for a particular event.
- Partner API

  - Transact against offers for a particular event (partners-only).
- Inventory Status API

  - Provides event status for primary Ticketmaster inventory with inventory.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer, I have downloaded ticketmaster via composer gigtoday/skd-ticketmaster in yii2. now i want to implement this in yii2, how can I add ticketmaster class in config/main.php, and how to use its classes ? this is yii2 specific question